# Heating element of my Oven is deriving huge power (10 KW)

Tags: electrical, oven

I have a Siemens oven and the upper baking element was faulty so I ordered a new one and tried to replace the faulty with a new heating element, but as soon as  I put my oven in operation the upper baking heating element was very quickly red within 30 seconds, and within another 10 seconds my electrical power tripped off. I did this twice but same story repeated.
I tried to troubleshoot and this time did not use the upper baking element and tested my oven (selecting only the bottom heating part) I did not notice any problem at all i,e it heated up to the desired temperature (i.e the thermostat was working fine) 
Conclusion :  When I use the whole oven (base , fan and upper heating element (baking element) the power that is derived by the oven shows about 10 KW (very high for a 2.8KW oven) and When I use only the base part of the oven the power is 2.3KW. Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like you ordered the wrong part. Have you double-checked the model number and spare part numbers? Have you asked Siemens about this?

Comment: The spare part ordered is not from Siemens but is same and manufactured by another company  EGO .  The heating element number that I bought mentions clearly my oven model number , ER number and ID in the list of ovens that this heating element goes with. They manufacture all spare parts  for Siemens Bosch models..  So I don't think that this could be the problem, nevertheless I cannot say anything about the new heating element itself, if is ok or faulty. I don't want to order another heating element suspecting that the fault may be somewhere else.

Comment: @Drew I doubt it, there's no one part that should draw 7kw.   This could be a lot of things, just a few include a measuring error or the oven not actually being the spec OP claims.  Or in the Euroscheme with multiphase supply, confusing L and N and accidentally putting 400v on a 230V coil.

Comment: @Harper  There is no measuring error as I checked it on my electric meter.  As far as connecting  the heating element is concerned, I connected the new heating element as the old one, I took pictures before removing the old one, so there is no such problem. Basically I wanted to know if there can be anything else that could be related to this increase in power in the upper heating element in case the newly installed element is ok.

Comment: How long did the old one last?

Comment: 4.5 years with regular use (once a week).  BTW,  can it be something to do with earthing.  Another point I would like to let you know is, the central part that runs to the 2 middle terminals does not heat up, only the outer part of the heating element that is connected to 2 extreme terminals gets excessively red.  I suspect that the new heating element is faulty. Not sure though.